# Long USB cable device not recognised

Tags: usb, cable

Hello i have a cable which have 4 cables inside. I attached a female USB port o the one side and the other is connected to my PC. The problem is that the cable is more than 5 meters and my PC does not recognize the connected to the port. How can i fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a proper USB cable.

Comment: Are you 100% the port works and that the USB is good?  Try a different USB on that port and try the USB cable in a different device to verify both components are working.  If they are, it might be something with the drivers on the PC so I would try an update.

Answer (score 4):

Your cable is to long.  5 meters is the [maximum length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) for a USB cable in optimal conditions.

From Wikipedia:

> USB 2.0 provides for a maximum cable length of 5 meters for devices running at Hi Speed (480 Mbit/s). The primary reason for this limit is the maximum allowed round-trip delay of about 1.5 μs. If USB host commands are unanswered by the USB device within the allowed time, the host considers the command lost. When adding USB device response time, delays from the maximum number of hubs added to the delays from connecting cables, the maximum acceptable delay per cable amounts to 26 ns.[47] The USB 2.0 specification requires that cable delay be less than 5.2 ns per meter (192 000 km/s, which is close to the maximum achievable transmission speed for standard copper wire).
>
> The USB 3.0 standard does not directly specify a maximum cable length, requiring only that all cables meet an electrical specification: for copper cabling with AWG 26 wires the maximum practical length is 3 meters (9.8 ft).[48]

Answer (score 3):

You need an active repeater to deal with the distance. Something like this would work: http://www.monoprice.com/Product/?p_id=6149